# What is the correct type for p5.js

Tags: reactjs, p5.js

I have installed `@types/p5@0.9.0` for `react-p5` but vs code isn't giving me any code hints for what type to use for p5 and I've reverted to `any` just to make it work, how should I go about finding the correct type to use?

```
import React from 'react';
import Sketch from 'react-p5';

const App: React.FC = () => {

  const setup = (p5: any) => {
    p5.createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  };

  const draw = (p5: any) => {
    p5.background(50);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Sketch setup={setup} draw={draw} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export { App };
```

Answer (score 0):

The interface is `p5InstanceExtensions`
So try:

```
import {p5InstanceExtensions} from 'p5';
...
const setup = (p5: p5InstanceExtensions) => {
```